# Stop javascript countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a countdown script using javascript. But i have one problem with stoped count down.

I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/eZodQq)** from codepen.io

In this demo you can see after page load the countdown will starting there is not have problem. But if you check it in developer console after fadeOut countdown then you can see the countdown still countinue like -1, -2, -3, ...

My question is how can i stop countdown after fadeOut ?

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var sec = 5
   var timer = setInterval(function() {
      $("#mdtimer span").text(sec--);
      if (sec == 0) {
         $("#makingdifferenttimer").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
         $("#mdtimer").hide(1000).fadeOut(fast);
      }
   }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: [fadeOut(fast, function(){clearInterval(timer)});](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-complete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `clearInterval()` function to stop the timer in `fadeOut` callback:

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

See [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-options) `complete` option.

Your updated example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var sec = 5
   var timer = setInterval(function() {
      $("#mdtimer span").text(sec--);
      if (sec == 0) {
         $("#makingdifferenttimer").delay(1000).fadeIn(1000);
         $("#mdtimer").hide(1000).fadeOut(500, function() {
            clearInterval(timer);
         });
      }
   }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: It is repeating  after  scrollup.

Comment: @martin your  answer need some  code because  it is repeating  after  scroll up